# Reading numeric values from a txt file in a batch

Tags: loops, batch-file

I have a loop in a batch file. I want to read the start and end values from a txt file. I have the files but I don't know exactly how to construct the loop. I have tried something like this:

```
for /L %%A in (firstYear.txt,1,lastYear.txt) do (
    copy data%%A.csv DATA
)
```

The text files include only one numeric value, in my case first and last years of a particular time series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set /p firstyear=<firstyear.txt
set /p lastyear=<lastyear.txt
for /L %%A in (%firstYear%,1,%lastYear%) do (
    copy data%%A.csv DATA
)
```

read each file into a variable; use the variables.

EDIT: I replaced '<' with '=<' because the former did not work for me. Otherwise perfect answer.